# Can you set the default save location for the git:clone command in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have not been able to find a configuration setting in vs code for the default git:clone command.  Is there a config setting that allows me to set the default save location for the git:clone command in vs code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that, *yet*. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17671), which received a [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/18567) back in January to accomplish this, but since VSCode updated the internals to support more SCM (other than Git), they asked to the contributor to re-send the PR in the new git-extension.

So, it will probably be available in newer releases.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the info.